# Erlang Cowboy crashing. How to change logging levels?

Tags: debugging, logging, crash, erlang, cowboy

I am running an Erlang Cowboy server and it strangely crashes sometimes with the error message:

```
> heart: Thu Dec 23 08:31:33 2021: Erlang has closed.
heart: Thu Dec 23 08:31:33 2021: Would reboot. Terminating.
gmake: *** [erlang.mk:7564: run] Killed
```

Lines 7564 in erlang.mk is

```
7563 run:: all
7564 $(verbose) $(RELX_OUTPUT_DIR)/$(RELX_REL_NAME)/bin/$(RELX_REL_NAME)$(RELX_REL_EXT) $(RELX_REL_CMD)
```

I am unable to figure out why it is crashing because I can find no logs.

The logs on the date of the crash are completely empty.

There are no core dumps on the OS or any crash dumps from Erlang.